# Protractor / Selenium XHR stays in status "pending"

Tags: selenium, testing, xmlhttprequest, protractor

I am using Protractor with selenium to test my Angular page.

At some random points, it justs stops the execution because an XHR-Request is still "pending" (in Chrome Dev Tools).

When I copy the request URL (it is a simple GET request) and open it in a new tab, it immediately returns the data (JSON, ~200 chars long).

The request stays "pending" when executing the E2E tests, and out of 10 times the said GET-URL gets called it fails maybe 1 time.

Selenium prints the following error: "Timed out receiving message from renderer: 298.388".

Any ideas?

Edit:

- Chrome version 71.0.3578.98
- Chromedriver version 2.45
- Selenium server version 3.141.59 (standalone)
- AngularJS v1.6.4

Comment: Please, provide your version of protractor, chrome, chrome driver and angular

Comment: Sorry, I've added the missing pieces of information :)

Comment: now, the code fails on every http request or there is only one particular? if so, could you also provide your angularjs code and respective protractor test kit?

Comment: No - it fails at random requests. It is not a back-end problem :/

Comment: well, to be honest, I don't know what is the problem so far, but let me suggest to update your project to the latest angularjs 1.7.x and to latest protractor version, I just start writing protractor tests and I do not have such a problem

Answer (score 1):

**As a last resort**, you can [execute JS](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript):

```
waitForAngular(function(browser, timeOut){
    pendingReq = browser.executeScript("var injector = window.angular.element('body').injector(); var $http = injector.get('$http'); return ($http.pendingRequests.length === 0);"
    if (timeOut >= 0){
        timeOut -= 1;
        if ( pendingReq ){
            return
        };
        else {
            waitForAngular(browser, timeOut)
        };
    };
    else {
    console.log("did not load in time");
    };
});
```

This is not a clean way to code but I have found it to help me with Angular App where Requests are still pending...

Hope you find this helpful!

**EDIT:**

The function above should work it may need some refactoring I did not test it...

Comment: Thank you! What does the script tho?

Comment: It uses the `injector()` to run on `$http` and return if the pending requests is 0...

Comment: try it in the console in your browser... `window.angular.element('body').injector().get('$http').pendingRequests.length === 0`

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't solve the problem, does it? I know there is a pending request that is blocking the page from loading / blocking protractor from executing. I don't see how a return value of "true" or "false" could solve this problem?

Comment: sorry... I was going to add a while loop with a brak point see my edit it will take a few minuts...

Comment: @jdstaerk I have updated the answer... you may want to change things around but the idea is in the answer...

Comment: @jdstaerk do you have any questions on this answer? did it help you?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. No, your solution does not solve the problem. I'm sorry. I've tried various stuff to solve this issue - none worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Your test didn't execute on time. So, you can increase the timeout in `protractor.conf.js` file.

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  ...
 /**
 * Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
 */
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000,
  ...
},
```

In the below link you can find various timeout arguments which you can configure in `protractor.conf.js`:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

---

If this doesn't solve your problem, then mostly it's because of some plugins or third-party ads.

**Refer:** https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/how-to-handle-time-out-receiving-message-from-the-renderer-in-chrome-driver/9140#9140

Comment: This is a good approach +1! I think if this doesn't work you should try my answer...